# How to retrieve manual change of system time/date from Android logs

Tags: android, logging, computer-forensics

i have an Android phone on which i need to find some artifact/logs/anything that could confirm that the system time/date was manually changed for a short period. The manipulation happened a while ago, not sure how relevant it is. I tried retrieving log files with logcat but looks like logs go back to only some minutes before i plug the phone into my laptop.